# JSF id value to the component behaves different

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have the following code in my xhtml

```
<h:form id="xyForm">
      <p:dataGrid id="xyGrid" ....>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="code" ...> </p:selectOneMenu>
      </p:dataGrid>
 </h:form>
```

But when I saw the code generated, it looks like the following

```
<select name="xyForm:xyGrid:0:code_input" tabindex="-1" id="xyForm:xyGrid:0:code_input"> </select>
```

My question here is: why `_input` is getting appended with name and `id.`

As per my understanding id should be only `xyForm:xyGrid:0:code` not with appended `_input`. Could someone please clarify or tell me how to remove that `_input`?

Answer (score 1):

An `id` attribute should be unique within an html page.

While rendering the SelectOneMenu, the `select` tag is wrapped inside a `div` tag. The `div` tag will have the id of the component i.e. `xyForm:xyGrid:0:code`, and so it makes sense that the select tag should have a different id.

Also, this is a common pattern in Primefaces, observed in other components like `SelectBooleanCheckbox` etc.

Instead of trying to removing `_input`, you will have to figure around how to work around it.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but when i try to access the select box like the following document.getElementById("xyForm:xyGrid:0:code_input") it gives null. i am basically trying to do the following document.getElementById("xyForm:xyGrid:0:code_input").selectedIndex = '-1';